# alternate row color and Can Grow field in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my report each row contains many fields and one of them is set to Can Grow. 
I have  alternate row color for easier row separation with a fomula like 
`if recordnumber mod 2 = 0 then crTeal else crNoColor`. 
However because the Can Grow field takes up multiple lines my alternate colors mess up.
Any idea how I can overcome this problem?

Not sure if the Can Grow field is the problem after all.
Sometimes I have for 2 or 3 rows the same color.

I have 3 groups like Products, status of Product (sold out etc..), Customer. I had to make a group for Customers because I wanted the latest date of a field and I read that this is a way to do it.

Comment: How many sections you are displaying the data and which section overlaps which section

Comment: Sory for late reply. I took a closer look and I am not sure if the Can Grow field is the problem.
Imagine the background colors alternate but sometime I have 2 or 3 rows with the same color.

Comment: Do you show data in details or in some group footer section? Do you suppress/hide some detail sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not with can grow...problem is with the formula.

When you have huge data and many groups then row number will generate the number which is not necessary the serial number and when you do modulus on that result will be one that you got.

Try this solution

Create a formula @initialise place in a section that is above the section where you show data

```
Shared numbervar counter;
counter:=0;
```

Create formula @count place in section where you show data

```
Shared numbervar counter;
counter:=counter+1;
```

Create a formula @reset place in a section after the section where you display the data

```
Shared numbervar counter;
counter:=0;
```

Now write your formula as

```
Shared numbervar counter;

 if counter mod 2 = 0 
then crTeal 
else crNoColor
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It won't work. The section where I display the data is a group. Same with the section above and the section below is actually the details..

Comment: Ok, so I placed the initialise at the section above the section I diplay the data, which is a Group and the @reset at the footer of the same Group. Works perfeclty! Thank you very much!!